# Integral of a partial derivative

Tags: integration, partial-derivative

In the image below, they've integrated a partial derivative. My questions is:

What happened to the constant of integration, a? How did they manage to get it into the logarithm?

[image]

Comment: The integral is $\ln s - ln a$ where $-\ln a = C$.

Comment: It is highly recommended as a part of "show your work" step in asking a question to avoid showing pictures of hand written notes and book pages, but to write down the equations and steps yourself. This also contributes to the overall quality of the content that can be found on this site.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll keep that in mind with all further question. Also, could I ask why I can express C as -ln(a)?

Comment: $C$ is an arbitrary real number and so is $-\ln(a)$ for $a\gt0$. Writing it in the latter form allows for a nicer-looking solution.