# Does an integral of a partial derivative make the partial derivative disappear?

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, definite-integrals, partial-derivative

I have often seen integrals such as

$$A = \int_{t=0}^{t=T}  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(t,x)  dt$$
and I'm wondering if the integral cancels the partial derivative when the variable that the $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ is the same as the $dt$ variable?

Does the integral cancel with the partial derivative or do both remain?
And, does the answer to that question change based if the $dt$ term had been $dx$?

Similar question: [Integral of a partial derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2733854/integral-of-a-partial-derivative)

Comment: Sure it does. You get $A(x)=\phi(T,x)-\phi(0,x)$

Comment: If you had $dx$ instead, then $\partial\phi/\partial t$ is just some function of $(t,x)$ with no special structure to be able to "cancel" it or express otherwise.

Comment: got it so in general $$A = \int_{t=0}^{t=T}  \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \phi(t,x)  dt \ne \phi(T,x)-\phi(0,x) $$ and also $$A = \int_{t=0}^{t=T}  \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \phi(t,x)  dx  \ne \phi(T,x)-\phi(0,x)  $$ right?

Comment: Absolutely right!