# What is the integral of a partial derivative?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative

I know this has been asked before but the answers didn't make sense to me. Can someone explain, preferably with a rigorous proof, why the single integral of a partial derivative of a function equals that function plus a function of the other variable? I want a general answer so one variable may be dependent on the other. ex: f[x(t), t]

[Integrating a Partial Derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754742/integrating-a-partial-derivative) which doesn't actually answer the question. It only gives the answer for specific cases.

https://math.stackexchange.com/a/606708/333261 gives the answer but it's explanation makes no sense to me. Why does it matter that y^2 goes to 0 after the partial? Additionally, I believe it assumes x and y to be independent variables so it is not a general answer.

[Integrating a partial derivative with second variable a function of the first?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2411923/integrating-a-partial-derivative-with-second-variable-a-function-of-the-first), [Does an integral of a partial derivative make the partial derivative disappear?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121095/does-an-integral-of-a-partial-derivative-make-the-partial-derivative-disappear), just state the answer. Their explanations don't make sense. I don't even understand their explanations enough to state what I don't understand about them.

Comment: What other answers have you read, and which part of them didn't make sense?

Comment: Which integral? Single integral? Double integral?

Comment: I have edited my question to clarify